# Journald allow a user to read one unit's logs

Tags: permissions, logging, systemd, journald

### tl;dr

How can I allow a normal user to read one systemd service's logs?

### Long question

Environment: CentOS 7

A user needs access to his service's logs, which are by default consumed by journald. I can view them as my non-root user (because I'm in the [wheel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_%28Unix_term%29) group), but the other user cannot. He will not get membership in wheel, but he needs his logs.

What permissions do I need to give him, so he can get to the logs? I would appreciate if he could run a standard journalctl command, like maybe

```
journalctl -f -u servicename.service
```

I guess if I have to, I can configure the service file specifically to log to a file, right? I guess I can have the ExecStart include a `| /usr/bin/tee -a /var/log/servicename.log` but why can't systemd handle this better?

Comment: Why not run the service under a user unit? Then the logs are always accessible to that user.